# Does shared index on Oracle table leads to deadlock?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, database-deadlocks

I am aware that unindexed foreign key in a child table can potentially lead to ORA-00060: deadlock. Similarly can a shared index can cause deadlock.

I have shared index in the following scenario,

```
class TableA {
int tableAId;
List<TableB> listOfTableB;
}

class TableB {
String name;
}
```

Related hibernate mapping (partial),

```
<list cascade="all,delete-orphan" name="listOfTableB" table="TableB">
        <key column="tableAId" />
        <index column="idx"/>
        <composite-element class="TableB">
            <property name="name" column="name" not-null="true" />
        </composite-element>
</list>
```

Using the above code, in DB it is creating a shared index (index of same name) for 'tableAId' and 'idx' in TableB.

In this scenario should I add a separate index for 'tableAId' alone inaddition to existing shared index to avoid deadlock ? Or the existing index itself is enough?

Comment: What is a 'shared index' in Oracle? that is not a term I would recognize.

Comment: I mean there are two columns in the table with same index_name. For the above case in SqlDeveloper Tables->TableB->Indexes view, i am seeing Index_Name-'SYS_C00309630' and columns 'TABLEAID, IDX' together

Comment: that sounds more like what you mean is you have an index on a composite value of 2 fields.

Comment: Oh Okay. That is what I meant when I said shared (sorry for my colloquial term). Do you think I need to add a separate index in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an index on `tableAId, idx` then there is probably (almost always) no benefit in also having an index on `tableAid` alone.  There is no danger of deadlock from this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the clarification.